# Jquery SetTimeout issue (I know posts already exists...)

Tags: jquery, timeout

I have a table with one column and four rows. Each tr has a class called 'ligne'. I also have a button. When clicked, I would like to run a each loop on the class 'ligne'. For each item I would like to give a blue background, but after sleeping for 1 second. I read a lot of posts, applied what i read, but it is not working. Hope someone can help me understand. Cheers. Marc

http://jsfiddle.net/M2ZCh/

my html:

```
<table>
  <tr class="ligne">
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ligne">
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ligne">
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ligne">
    <td>four</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<input id="btn-timeout" type="submit" value="timeout!"/>
```

my js:

```
$(document).on({
    click: function() {

        $(".ligne").each(function() {

            setTimeout(function() {

                $(this).css('background', 'blue');

            }, 1000);

        });


    }

}, "#btn-timeout");​
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/M2ZCh/1/

Comment: Hello tim. This is not what I am looking for. I would like each tr to set to blue with 1 second interval... Thanks anyway

Comment: @Marc, Do you mean one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version which highlights each cell one by one: http://jsfiddle.net/M2ZCh/9/

```
$(document).on({
    click: function() {
        var index = 0;
        $(".ligne").each(function() {
            var obj = $(this); // pin reference to element

            setTimeout(function() {
                obj.css('background', 'blue');
            }, 1000 * ++index);
        });
    }
}, "#btn-timeout");​
```

Comment: @Marc, you should not iterate against each rows, to do this. This slows down the effect you want by a lot.

Comment: @Tim I just took this example to simplify. I am not looking for an affect. I will implement this in an each loop that runs hundreds of time, and execute every time an ajax call. I want this delay in order not to overload my server with so much simultaneous requests...

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that the scope of `this` had changed inside the `setTimeout` function

```
$(".ligne").each(function(index) {   
    var self = $(this); // reference for this
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.css('background', 'blue');
    }, 1000 * ++index);
});
```

here is a working copy:
http://jsfiddle.net/M2ZCh/11/

Comment: Sorry there was a type. Fixed.

Comment: Hello Bjarki. What I am looking for is not that. What I would like is the first tr to be set and blue, then wait 1 second, then the second tr in blue, then wait 1 second......

Comment: Added a 1 sec delay so now you are getting the expected result :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, as this

```
$("#btn-timeout").click(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
       $(".ligne").css("background","blue");
    }, 1000);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/M2ZCh/7/)

**Update:**

If you want each boxes to changed background consequently then, you have to use `setInterval()` instead.

```
var tlenth = $(".ligne").length;
$("#btn-timeout").click(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var int = setInterval(function () {
       $(".ligne").eq(i).css("background","blue");
        i++;
        if(i>tlenth-1) { clearInterval(int); }
    }, 1000);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/M2ZCh/13/)

Comment: Hello Starx. Thanks for jumping in once again. Your suggestion is nevertheless not what I am looking for. I want the first tr to be set to blue, wait 1 sec, The second tr in blue, wait 1 sec.....

Comment: That's it !! Thank you very much. I did not knew that setInterval method. Problem solved. You rock...

Comment: @Marc, Just a minor update. I cached the total length of the rows and fixed the clearInterval

Answer (score 2):

I've came up with a solution for your problem:

[Here an example](http://jsfiddle.net/M2ZCh/2/)

The problem was that

`$(this).css('background', 'blue')` doesn't refer to the html element since it's encapsulated in the setTimeout function.

So you need yo extract the current html element by doing

```
var $this = $(this);
```

**EDIT:**

I've added the code from the jsFiddle bellow:

```
$(document).on({
click: function() {
    $(".ligne").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.css('background', 'blue');
        }, 1000);
    });
 }
}, "#btn-timeout");
```

Comment: Hello Bogdan. This is not what I am looking for. I would like each tr to set to blue with 1 second interval... Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line `$(this).css(...`. You can't use `this` in `setTimeout` since it will refer to the `document` not the actual element that you're dealing with.

Try this.

```
    $(".ligne").each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {

            el.css('background', 'blue');

        }, 1000);

    });
```